# Why are there two parentheses after `let` in emacs lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp, parentheses

I'm doing a [tutorial](http://emacs-doctor.com/learn-emacs-lisp-in-15-minutes.html) on emacs lisp, and it's talking about the `let` function.

```
;; You can bind a value to a local variable with `let':
(let ((local-name "you"))
  (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*test*")
  (erase-buffer)
  (hello local-name)
  (other-window 1))
```

I don't understand the role of the double parentheses after `let` in the first line. What are they doing that a single set wouldn't do? Running that section without them, I get an error: `Wrong type argument: listp, "you"`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can introduce multiple variables there.  The outer parentheses delimit the list of bindings, the inner the individual binding form.

```
(let ((foo "one")
      (bar "two"))
  (frobnicate foo bar))
```

Comment: Thanks! How come we don't need the single quote '(...) for that varlist while in other circumstances we do need '(...) to make a list?

Comment: @Hatshepsut: `let` is a special form that has its own evaluation rules.  Quoting a form is only for when the evaluation rules for the containing form would otherwise try to evaluate it.  Special forms are usually designed with sensible evaluation rules that minimize extra syntax.

Answer (score 8):

There are **not** "*double parens*".

Presumably, you are thinking of `(let ((foo...)...))`, and you mean the `((` that come after `let`?  If so, consider this:

```
(let (a b c) (setq a 42)...)
```

IOW, `let` ***declares*** local variables.  It **may** also ***bind*** them.  In the previous sexp, it declares `a`, `b`, and `c`, but it doesn't bind any of them, leaving it to the `let` body to give them values.

An example that declares two variables but binds only one of them (`a`):

```
(let ((a 42) b) ... (setq b ...) ...)
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Parts-of-let-Expression.html#Parts-of-let-Expression), it looks like you can construct and initialize multiple variables with one let statement, so the double parenthesis is there to allow the separation between the variables.

> If the varlist is composed of two-element lists, as is often the case, the template for the let expression looks like this:
>
> ```
> (let ((variable value)
>       (variable value)
>       …)
>   body…)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The `let` special form takes a list of bindings: `(let (<binding-form> ...) <body>)`.

The binding form is one of `<symbol>` (denoting a variable bound to the value `nil`) or a list `(<symbol> <value>)` (where value is computed when the `let` is entered).

The difference between `let` and `let*` is how the "value" bits are executed. For plain `let`, they're executed before any of the values are bound:

```
(let ((a 17) 
      (b 42)) 
  (let ((a b)  ; Inner LET
        (b a)) 
    (list a b)))
```

Whereas `let*` executes the binding forms one after another. Both have their places, but you can get by with only using `let` since `(let* (<form1> <form2>...)` is equivalent to `(let (<form1>) (let (<form2>) ...))`